# Python, Pandas, inverted expanding window

Tags: python, pandas

Lets consider the following Series:

```
s=pd.Series(data=[100, 110, 120, 150, 110, 90, 80, 70, 90, 95])
```

I iterate over each item and perform the following operation:

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    m=max(s[i]-s[i:])
```

Basically comparing each item with all items that follow, and retrieving the max.

I can do that with:

```
r=[]
for i in range(len(s)):
    m=max(s[i]-s[i:])
    r.append(m)

result=pd.Series(r)
```

But I had the feeling that this would be something that a rolling window could do? I am trying to make my code a bit cleaner and was just starting reading and exploring about the rolling function, but i cannot yet but my finger on it. This idea seems like a inverted expanding function (i.e. it takes less and less data as it goes down the data)?

If someone has ideas about how to reformat the code using rolling / expanding windows, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the initial series using `[::-1]`, take the cumulative min value, then reverse again.  Subtract the resulting series from `s`.

```
>>> s.sub(s[::-1].cummin()[::-1])

0    30
1    40
2    50
3    80
4    40
5    20
6    10
7     0
8     0
9     0
dtype: int64
```

If the index is monotonically increasing, one can be more explicit:

```
s.sub(s.sort_index(ascending=False).cummin().sort_index())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `numpy.minimum.accumulate` on `s` reversed and then subtract it from `s`:

```
import numpy as np
s - np.minimum.accumulate(s[::-1])[::-1]

#0    30
#1    40
#2    50
#3    80
#4    40
#5    20
#6    10
#7     0
#8     0
#9     0
#dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Or we can using `rolling` and `min`

```
s-s[::-1].rolling(len(s),min_periods=1).min()
Out[368]: 
0    30.0
1    40.0
2    50.0
3    80.0
4    40.0
5    20.0
6    10.0
7     0.0
8     0.0
9     0.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yes I think that's as close as it gets. Thx!

Comment: @jimbasquiat Yw~ :-) happy coding